# How to replace multiple line with increment number with padding in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this lines :

```
_____0000_____
_____0000_____
_____0000_____
_____0000_____
....
```

I want to replace the 0000 with increment padded number ( incremented by 10) :

```
_____0010_____
_____0020_____
_____0030_____
_____0040_____
....
_____0090_____
_____0100_____
_____0110_____
```

Comment: This extension looks useful: [Insert Numbers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Asuka.insertnumbers). I just googled "vscode insert numbers".

Answer (score 0):

you can use the extension I wrote: [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen)

- with Multi-Cursor select the `0000` part of every line.

  - you can do it with select first `0000` and then use `Ctrl+D` to select a few more
  - or select first `0000`, `Ctrl+F` `Alt+Enter`
- execute command: **Generate text based on Regular Expression (regex)**
- as match regex use: `.*`
- as generator regex use: `{{=(i+1)*10:size(4)}}`

If you have blank lines and want to generate the whole text use:

- place Multi-Cursor on all lines:

  - place cursor on first line
  - `Shift+Alt+Click` on last line
- execute command: **Generate text based on Regular Expression (regex)**
- as match regex use: `.*`
- as generator regex use: `_____{{=(i+1)*10:size(4)}}_____`

If you need to do this regular you can define a preset in the settings with these properties that are editable when selected.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy with an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).  With it you can select what you want to replace with a `find` regex and do the math to construct the replacement.

Try this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json` or it could be a command):

```json
{
  "key": "alt+c",                    // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "description": "replace 0000 with 0010, 0020, etc.",  // any description

    "find": "(?<=_____)(0000)(?=_____)",
    "isRegex": true,

    "replace": [         // replace with a javascript operation result
      "$${",
                         // make a String(...) so can use padStart next
        "let result = String(${matchNumber} * 10);",
        "return result.padStart(4, '0');",
      "}$$",
    ],
    "postCommands": "cancelSelection",  // to remove all the selections on each line

  },
},
```

There are many more options in the extension if you need them.  Demo:

[image: replace selection with math operation demo]

Comment: I got this error : command 'findInCurrentFile' not found

Comment: Did you install the extension?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install any extensions, one workaround you could use is to just nuke those lines and then recreate them using Emmet. You'd open a new untitled editor, change the language mode to one that Emmet will apply to (which you can configure), such as HTML, then write something like `_____$$$_____*N`, where `N` is the number of lines you want to create. See multiplication and line numbering in [the Emmet cheatsheet](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) for more info. Since I don't think Emmet can do steps other than incrementing by one, you need to add the zeros for the step-by-ten by using [rectangular selection](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_column-box-selection) and pressing zero.

I would have suggested to use multi-cursor editing combined with [snippets and multi-cursor snippet variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables), but the padding zeroes complicate things for that approach.

Comment: how do you get the step 10 with Emmet

Comment: @rioV8 edited. thanks.

Comment: step 10 is easy [add a zero] ;-), but what if he wants step 7 the next time

Comment: @rioV8 then this doesn't work and they should use a different answer here :)